# measuring method execution time using Unity interception

Tags: profiling, unity-container, aop

Do you know a pattern for method execution time measurement using EntLib's Unity and its interception mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `ICallHandler` (or very similar `IInterceptionBehavior` in Unity 2.0) implementation like below and add it to your object's execution timeline

```
public class MeasurementHandler : ICallHandler
{
  public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input,
                               GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
  {
    StartTimer(); // implement it :)
    IMethodReturn msg = getNext()(input, getNext);  
    StopTimer(); // implement it :)
    return msg;
  }
}
```